# Want to restrict the local machine IP,Instead of local ip the server will see salesforce Ip or id

Tags: api, salesforce, apex, apex-code

I want to restrict the local machine IP,Instead of local ip the server will see salesforce Ip or id.

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8T0z.png)

See the image for example:
image cloud will see the Salesforce ID or IP not the local machine IP or id of user.

Let say in my contact page, i have to put user image from URL field and that image was on some other website and that website requires Authentication or IP address of mine for accessing it, so i want that it shows the salesforce ip or authentication login instead of mine IP.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In what context? Salesforce is not a proxy server or VPN. Please [edit] your post with a detailed description _in words_ of the connected systems.

Comment: Let say in my contact page, i have to put user image from URL field and that image was on some other website and that website requires Authentication or IP address of mine for accessing it, so i want that it shows the salesforce ip or authentication login instead of mine IP.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to host images related to a contact on one service and only allow access if they are logged into Salesforce. You can do that, but not through IP restrictions or file proxies (well maybe you could do the second, but you don't really want to). Usually people use a some form of URL signing solution that has Salesforce generate a query parameter on the image URL that is then validated on the image's server before sending the file to the browser.